# R Shiny include pieces of code (i.e. markdown) directly in UI

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

I try to include pieces of raw SQL code in the UI of my Shiny application, including code highlighting, but I can't find a way to do this directly.

In short about the application: I let users choose some parameters in dropdowns, which creates a dynamic SQL query, and I want to print this query to show users what happens. Illustrative example here:

[image]

I was thinking about including a piece of markdown, because it brings automatically the code highlighting of the SQL query, but can't find a direct way to output pieces of Markdown code.

Markdown would be like:

````
```sql
SELECT a
      ,b
      ,c
      ,d
FROM table1
```
````

I know it is possible to [include a complete markdown document](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/include.html), using `includeMarkdown(path)`. But since the query is dynamic, I want to output the markdown content directly.

After quite some Googling, I could not find a way to directly output (and mark up) some SQL code in my Shiny application. Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a (quite heavy) way of solving this, using the `ShinyAce package`, which renders a text editor in your Shiny application.

Working example in Shiny can be found [here](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce/tree/master/inst/examples/01-basic).

For me this means that I can include the `aceEditor()` object in the `UI.R` and update the SQL statement (simple piece of text) on the server side. I can then update the AceEditor using `updateAceEditor(session, "ace", value = sqlQuery)` where `sqlQuery` holds the plain SQL query.